# Stop processing PHP script / alternative to goto

Tags: php

Is there a better way than `goto` to achieve this:

**index.php:**

```
echo "Welcome to our site";
require 'showPonies.php';
echo "I hope you enjoyed your stay!";
```

**showPonies.php:**

```
...
if (isset($_GET['noponies'])
  goto EXITSCRIPT;
...

// This is the end of the file
EXITSCRIPT:
?>
```

Specifically I am looking for a way inside `showPonies.php` to "`exit(0)`" the script and return processing from where it was `include`d/`require`d.

Comment: That's what `return` already does.

Comment: What your doing is correct. You could have your 'exitscript:' in index.php if you wanted.

Comment: @MattTheNinja It is "correct" in the extremely limited sense that it will have the desired effect. It is *not* correct in that "goto considered harmful". Also, [raptors!](http://php.net/goto)

Comment: @mario You say that like nobody could possibly not know that. I've been programming in PHP for years, and only recently came upon that use of `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`return`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) construct for this:

```
if (isset($_GET['noponies']))
    return;
```

From the doc:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was included or required, then control is passed back to the calling file.

Comment: Looks like I can work with this. Thanks!